# The 'XamarinShellPackage' package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I have encountered the following error:

> The 'XamarinShellPackage' package did not load correctly.

It happens when i start Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3 Or Visual studio 15 Preview 4.
I even reinstalled windows 10 and it doesn't help.

As asked, pasting VS info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 15 Preview 4
Version 15.0.25618.0 PREVIEW
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

Installed Version: Enterprise
Visual Basic 15 Preview 4   00369-50000-00000-AA551   
Visual C# 15 Preview 4   00369-50000-00000-AA551    
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2016   15.0.20802.0    
Common Azure Tools   1.8    
JavaScript Language Service   2.0    
JavaScript Project System   2.0    
JavaScript UWP Project System   2.0    
NuGet Package Manager   3.5.0    
Parallel Debugger   1.0    
SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.60805.0    
TypeScript   2.0.1.0    
Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova   Update 10    
Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.25618.00    
Xamarin   4.1.1.8 (60e5c00)    
Xamarin.Android   6.1.1.1 (7db2aac)    
Xamarin.iOS   9.8.1.4 (3cf8aae)
```

Comment: Is this only with a specific project or even if you create a new Xamarin project? And is it a Xamarin Forms, or Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android project?

Comment: Even before i create. Also while creating a new one. All of them.

Comment: Have you reinstalled Xamarin?

Comment: Very surprised you're seeing the same error after a reinstall of Windows! Can you try deleting the contents of your Component Model Cache and see if that helps? Close VS, then clear contents of: C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache

Comment: @Matt: Will try now.

Comment: @AlanClark: Didn't help. thanks.

Comment: Can you share your full version information? Visual Studio > Help > About

Comment: @Matt: Didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: @AlanClark: shared.

Comment: @Dorad Your tooling looks a few months out of date there. Would you be willing to update to latest stable and report back? Visual Studio > Tools > Xamarin > Other

Comment: Cannot open 'Visual Studio > Tools > Xamarin > Other', it generates the same error from the question plus "An error occured loading this property page"

Comment: Is that in VS15 or VS2015?  I'd appreciate you sticking to Stable builds of VS until we've found the source of the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124653/discussion-between-dorad-and-alan-clark).

Comment: For anyone who got here, the problem wasn't solved.

Comment: @Dorad if you found solution plz share it here, so it will be helpfull for others like me.

Comment: @Jaydeep Karena I gave up Xamarin after that.

Comment: OK thanks for reply

Answer (score 3):

The tooling in the version information here is a little out of date.  The solution in this case was to perform a [thorough uninstall of Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/visual_studio_with_xamarin/troubleshooting/uninstall-xamarinvs/) in Windows and reinstall using the latest available Stable release.  I linked @Dorad to the direct download, but you can find this by signing into Xamarin.com, navigating to the [Downloads page](https://store.xamarin.com/account/me/subscription/downloads) and selecting the download from the relevant drop-down list for your OS / desired Xamarin platform:

[image]

Comment: your download link dumps you out on pricing page now.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick thing people can try that worked for me was deleting the `.vs` folder from the root of the solution folder. Make sure VS is closed when you do it.

Comment: plz tell me the location of `.vs` folder

Comment: @JaydeepKarena it should be in the same folder as your solution (.sln) file. It is also a hidden folder so it may not be invisible via the explorer window. You can show hidden files and folders via the settings in explorer, or use cmd prompt to find it and delete it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a potential workaround you may want to try while we finish up a fix for this.

Please, close all open VS instance and copy this file (note you may need to adjust the path to your specific VS instance):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\netstandard.dll"

to the Xamarin extension folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin.VisualStudio

And then open VS and check if you can still repro.

thanks,

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem after the latest VS2017 update..I resolved uninstalling an extension (Visual Studio Bitbucket plugin) which - apparently - was in conflict with XamarinShellPackage. Removing the extension and restarting VS did the trick for me.