# Installing Xamarin in Visual studio professional

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have been trying to install Xamarin on my machine.  I have been following this article [Installing Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows)

1. Visual studio is 15.8.1. professional.
2. Windows 10
3. Downloaded from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Professional&rel=15#) about two hours ago.

The install appears to go well.  About says its installed

[image]

I tried to confirue it now [Windows Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/windows#configuration)
But i cant open the window as i get an error.  which points me over to a log file

[image]

There is loads of stuff in this file i am not sure what i am looking for to find out what the issue is.

> SetSite failed for package XamarinShellPackage

and

> End package load [XamarinShellPackage]

and

> LegacySitePackage failed for package [XamarinShellPackage]Source: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition' Description: Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Clide.IDevEnv" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Clide.IDevEnv" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition importDefinition)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports[T,TMetadataView](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T,TMetadataView](String contractName)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T](String contractName)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportT
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueT
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetServiceT
>    at Clide.DevEnv.Get(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in D:\a\1\s\src\Clide.Interfaces\DevEnv.cs:line 12
>    at Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage.Initialize() in E:\A_work\53\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\FlavorProject\TastyPackage.cs:line 116
>    at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Shell.XamarinShellPackage.Initialize() in E:\A_work\53\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Shell\XamarinShellPackage.cs:line 67
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)

**What I tried**

1. Restarting visual studio and rebooting have not helped.
2. This error now popups when every i try to load a project.
3. I do not have Bitbucket

What am i missing?

Comment: have a look at [The 'XamarinShellPackage' package did not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717887/the-xamarinshellpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly/51167176#51167176) it might help.

Comment: I did download the latest version from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Professional&rel=15#) about two hours ago.  I dont have anything called Bitbucket installed.

Comment: as per [issue resolved in 15.4 preview](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/111524/xamarininspectorpackage-package-did-not-load-corre.html) document, they have resolved the known issue. And here is one more [recent](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/125620/the-xamarinshellpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly) article about it in xamarin forum

Comment: My current version of visual studio is 15.8.1.   Both of those articles are quite old and would probably not be related to a new install if as you say it was fixed previously.   Could this be a reintroduced bug?

Comment: have you tried the solution mentioned in the xamarin forum? like manually loading the Android SDK manager.

Comment: [Your forum link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/125620/the-xamarinshellpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly) says remove Bitbucket which i dont have. and some other stuff which i do not understand.   I have never installed this before i have 0 mobile development experience.  If you have any ideas your going to need to be more specific as to what you want me to try.   Clicking on **Android SDK manager** does nothing

Comment: start VS2017 installer and select repair to repair VS

Comment: Well that's one thing I didn't try.   I will let you know Monday when I get back to work

Comment: @magicandre1981 repair didnt help.  I am going to try and remove it

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and haven't figured out the problem either. If you find the solution I'm happy to hear what solved it.

Comment: Same issue in 15.8.1 on win10latest, repair didn't help :(

Comment: I posted a link to the Microsoft community with a workaround, try it @DaImTo

Comment: @AK also look at my answer and try it.

Comment: Updating VS from 15.8.1 to [15.8.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.8.2) fix this issue for me. It's so strange, but there's nothing about this issue in release notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is [already reported to Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/312602/after-updating-vs-2017-to-1580-error-when-opening.html) and Microsoft posted a Workaround:

> There is a potential workaround you may want to try while we finish up
>   a fix for this.
>
> Please, close all open VS instance and copy this file (note you may
>   need to adjust the path to your specific VS instance):
>
> ```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\netstandard.dll"
> ```
>
> to the Xamarin extension folder:
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin.VisualStudio
> ```
>
> And then open VS and check if you can still repro.

Comment: wonder how long it will take them to fix it I uninstalled it Monday I can try again on Friday and let you know if this fixes it

Comment: tbw, which windows 10 do you use? The LTSB from 2016 or the current 1803?

Comment: to see the version run **winver.exe** or cmd.exe and run **ver**. .net standard 2.0 support was added with Windows 10 v1709/Build 16299. if you use an older Build like 14393 this cause cause the error.

Comment: @magicandre1981 IT just rolled out a new version last week. Edition: Windows 10 Enterprise Version: 1709 OS Build: 16299.15.   I am kind of locked to what they deploy to us.

Comment: 1709 has .net standard 2.0 support. Install 15.8.2, it fixed the issue for @AK.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it was an issue on Microsofts side.  I just updated visual studio to `15.8.2` then i did a modify to add Xamarin under five minutes later it was done with the install.  Last week it was more then 10 minutes.

[image]

Configure screen now works and i can open a project.